# SQL - Denormalized Data Export to flat file mixed delimiter

Tags: sql, db2

I have a flat, denormalized table:

```
PRODUCT_ID     LOCATION        PARTNUMBER      PRICE   STATUS
1234567890     9999            5555            10.99   A
1234567890     8888            5555            11.99   A
1234567890     7777            5555             9.99   B
9876543210     9999            3333            15.99   A
9876543210     4444            3333            14.99   A
...
```

I need to query this to produce an output file that looks something like this:

```
1234567890|9999|5555|10.99|A,8888|5555|11.99|A,7777|5555|9.99|B
9876543210|9999|3333|15.99|A,4444|3333|14.99|A
...
```

So basically a data format of:

Product_ID|LOCATION1|PARTNUMBER1|PRICE1|STATUS1,LOCATIONN|PARTNUMBERN|PRICEN,STATUSN,...

I'm unsure of where to start here....should I use a nested query?

Comment: For MySQL, SQL-Server, Postgres, Oracle, ...?

Comment: So, you want to **denormalize** a normalized table?

Comment: You _are_ aware that you're basically giving up the right to use most `load` type of functions, right?  I know DB2 on the iSeries won't accept unlimited/jagged length lines when attempting to load to a (individual columns) tables (not sure where you're using it).  Whoever you give it to will likely have to parse it out individually; I'd much rather have an 'export' of the table.  Oh, this data may not be completely normalized anyways...

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a cursor to loop through your table.
Use a variable to control if each line of the table refers to the same product or a new product.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @OLD_PRODUCT_ID int
set @OLD_PRODUCT_ID = -1

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR 
select PRODUCT_ID, LOCATION, PARTNUMBER, PRICE, STATUS
FROM YourTable

OPEN MyCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor 
INTO @PRODUCT_ID, @LOCATION, @PARTNUMBER, @PRICE, @STATUS --declare these variables

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    if (@PRODUCT_ID = @OLD_PRODUCT_ID) begin
        -- use the same line
    end ele begin
        -- new product = new line
    end

    @OLD_PRODUCT_ID = @PRODUCT_ID
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor 
    INTO @PRODUCT_ID, @LOCATION, @PARTNUMBER, @PRICE, @STATUS

END
CLOSE MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
```

Comment: Don't forget the ORDER BY on the select statement or this won't work!

Answer (score 0):

There are also ways to do this w/o looping, but the sql is harder.

Is the list of locations bounded and small?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
select a.product_id || 
     coalesce((select '|' || b.location || '|' || b.partnumber  || '|' || 
                             b.price || '|' || trim(b.status)  || ','
               from session.products b 
               where b.location = '9999' and b.product_id = a.product_id), '') || 

     coalesce((select '|' || c.location || '|' || c.partnumber  || '|' || 
                                 c.price || '|' || trim(c.status)  || ','
               from session.products c 
               where c.location = '8888' and c.product_id = a.product_id), '') 
from (select distinct product_id as product_id from session.products) as a
```

where you extend the statement for each location.

There are ways to do this for an unbounded set of locations in sql, but it's not easy to read/write/debug and the cursor solution by +Diego may be more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, you can this recursively:

```
WITH Ordered_Data (product_id, orderIndex, dataString) as (
     SELECT product_id, location, partnumber, price, status, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION_BY product_id ORDER BY product_id, location ASC),
            product_id || '|' || location || '|' || partnumber || '|' ||     
            price || '|' || status   
     FROM Product_Location),

     Combined_Data(product_id, orderIndex, dataString) as (
     SELECT a.product_id, a.orderIndex, a.dataString
     FROM Ordered_Data as a
     JOIN (SELECT product_id, MAX(orderIndex) as orderIndex
           FROM Ordered_Data 
           GROUP BY product_id) as b
     ON b.product_id = a.product_id
     AND b.orderIndex = a.orderIndex
     UNION ALL
     SELECT b.product_id, a.orderIndex, b.dataString || ',' || a.dataString
     FROM Ordered_Data as a
     JOIN Combined_Data as b
     ON b.product_id = a.product_id
     AND b.orderIndex - 1 = a.orderIndex)

SELECT dataString
FROM Combined_Data
WHERE orderIndex = 1
```

Which yields the expected:

```
9876543210|9999|3333|15.99|A,9876543210|4444|3333|14.99|A                            
1234567890|9999|5555|10.99|A,1234567890|8888|5555|11.99|A,1234567890|7777|5555|9.99|B
```

I make no guarantees of how *fast* this will run - in particular, you're going to want an index over (`product_id`, `location`) (or similar, and tweak the statement).  I believe that DB2 is smart enough to read indicies backwards, so the direction shouldn't matter quite so much.

As a side note, I **really** hope `price` is `numeric` or `decimal` (precise decimals), and not `float` or `real`.